# Grouping/clustering long repeating results into columns of data

Tags: mysql

I am collecting some information in mysql instead of excel. There are some labels defined for each cell type, and not all labels maybe present. So, I have 3 label, information and cell tables.

```
select cell_name, label, information from onco_celldb_information as info 
left join onco_celldb_cells as cell on cell.`celldb_cell_id` = info.`celldb_cell_id`
left join onco_celldb_labels as label on info.`celldb_label_id` = label.`celldb_label_id`
order by cell.celldb_cell_id asc;
```

which results into:

[running query above http://f.cl.ly/items/0m2k1a410s3D0K2Y0l1u/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-22%20at%2011.57.36%20AM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/0m2k1a410s3D0K2Y0l1u/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-22%20at%2011.57.36%20AM.png)

However what I want is to have something like this:

```
CellName    Species     CellType    Origin
---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
P-815      Murine      Mastroxxxx    Human
L292      Something      Megatrone    Mouse
```

So to have them grouped by cellname, and have the results as columns. If the labels are not present just have NULL there (some results may not have a label present).

What do you suggest?

Edit with database structure:

```
mysql> describe celldb_cells;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| celldb_cell_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cell_name      | varchar(256)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe celldb_information;
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| celldb_information_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| celldb_cell_id        | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| celldb_label_id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| information           | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe celldb_labels;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| celldb_label_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| label           | varchar(256)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: how many distinct labels are there?

Comment: Do you know the number of labels that you want as columns?

Comment: around 23, but I it is dynamic. So, once I collect the data I know which labels I have and is not a fixed number.

Comment: Do you know the exact set of labels that will appear as columns in the result in advance. Or the actual set of labels would be generated on the fly from the actual data in `onco_celldb_labels`?

Comment: It is so: (1) Import all the pdfs into system, so I have all the labels (on the fly) and associated information linked to cells, (2) generate the excel sheet, where I need this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of the labels then it is possible to "pivot" the data so that rows become labels.

```
select cell_name,
  max(case when info.celldb_label_id = 1 then information else NULL end) as LabelForInfo1,
  max(case when info.celldb_label_id = 2 then information else NULL end) as LabelForInfo2,
  max(case when info.celldb_label_id = 3 then information else NULL end) as LabelForInfo3,
  ..
from
 onco_celldb_cells as cell
 left join onco_celldb_information as info on cell.celldb_cell_id = info.celldb_cell_id
group by cell.celldb_cell_id, cell.cell_name
order by cell.celldb_cell_id asc;
```

If number and names of labels are not known - you can construct the query above dynamically on the basis of the information in `onco_celldb_labels`. So first of all generate the "dynamic" columns for the above query, by executing the following query:

```
select concat(
  'max(case when info.celldb_label_id = ',
   convert(celldb_label_id,char),
   ' then information else NULL end) as `',
   label,
   '`,')
from celldb_labels
```

Now join **all the returned rows** in one string, add beginning and end from the main query and execute. This way you have dynamic labels. As far as I know it is the only way to pivot table in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't want to hardcode the labels. This why I have a labels tables -- since new data sources will bring new labels.

Comment: As I stated - you do not need to hardcode labels. Simply generate statement using data in `onco_celldb_labels` and execute this generated statement.

Comment: @DanialTz I update my answer with additional query that can be used to generate part of the main query.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is called a `PIVOT` and unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function but you can replicate it using `CASE` statements and an aggregate function.

If you know all of the labels ahead of time and the number of them is manageable, then you could hard-code them similar to this:

```
SELECT cell_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN label = 'Cell Type' THEN information END) 'Cell Type',
  MAX(CASE WHEN label = 'DSMZ no.' THEN information END) 'DSMZ no.'
FROM test
GROUP BY cell_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7582/1)

With your query, you would do something like:

```
SELECT cell_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN label = 'Cell Type' THEN information END) 'Cell Type',
  MAX(CASE WHEN label = 'DSMZ no.' THEN information END) 'DSMZ no.'
from onco_celldb_information as info 
left join onco_celldb_cells as cell 
  on cell.`celldb_cell_id` = info.`celldb_cell_id`
left join onco_celldb_labels as label 
  on info.`celldb_label_id` = label.`celldb_label_id`
GROUP BY cell_name
```

However, it looks like you are going to have an unknown number of columns, so you will want to use a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when label = ''',
      label,
      ''' then information end) AS ''',
      label, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM test;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT cell_name, ', @sql, ' FROM test
group by cell_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7582/18)

So for your specific example if would be something like:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when label = ''',
      label,
      ''' then information end) AS ''',
      label, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM onco_celldb_labels;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT cell_name, ', @sql, ' 
from onco_celldb_information as info 
left join onco_celldb_cells as cell 
  on cell.`celldb_cell_id` = info.`celldb_cell_id`
left join onco_celldb_labels as label 
  on info.`celldb_label_id` = label.`celldb_label_id`              
group by cell_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your detailed explaination helped me form my query without copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very pretty solution, but if you only want a couple of the labels as columns and you can specify which ones, something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    s1.cell_name AS cell_name,
    s2.information AS Species,
    s3.information AS Origin
    -- Keep adding selects here for more columns
FROM
    (SELECT distinct cell_name FROM onco_celldb_information) AS s1
    LEFT JOIN onco_celldb_information AS s2
        ON (s1.cell_name = s2.cell_name AND s2.label = 'Species')
    LEFT JOIN onco_celldb_information AS s3
        ON (s1.cell_name = s3.cell_name AND s3.label = 'Origin')
    -- Keep adding more joins here for further columns you want.
```